# pod is not recognized as an internal or external command in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-linking

I've installed *image picker* in my react native project and i am going to link the package in ios

I run these commands:

```
cd ios && pod install
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
pod is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I am coding in windows 7 and my react native version is: "0.61.5"

How can i fix this?

Comment: `pod intall` command does not work on windows. It only in IOS.

Comment: I am building an app, I need this app works on both of android and ios, Some libraries need to run ```pod install``` during installation process, In this case how can i make compatible such libraries with ios?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pod` is command for [Cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started), dependency manager for [xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) project, so it means that cocoapods is expected to be running on macOS. However if you want to try, you can see [this](https://medium.com/@airtdave/using-cocoapods-on-windows-dec471735f51) article about running `pod` commands on windows.

Answer (score 0):

In windows you add path of npm module (C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Roaming\npm) to system variables instead of user variables

[image: r]

In Mac or Linux:

Try installing react-native-cli globally by

`npm install -g react-native-cli`

Comment: I changed path of npm from to  user variables to system variables right now but issue is persisting and i am getting same error

Comment: @roz333 can you please share the path which yo have updated?

Comment: @ro333 Also did you tried installing react-native-cli globally `npm install -g react-native-cli`

Comment: Yes my project was installed globally in the first place